# Keep getting "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" when trying to use this JS code to answer Project Euler 5?

Tags: javascript

Problem 5:
2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.

What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

My code to attempt the solution:

```
var x = 2520;
var div = 20;
var smallest = function(){
    while (div > 0){
        if (x%div ===0){
            div = div - 1;
            smallest();
        }
        else{
            x = x+1;
            div = 20;
            smallest()
        }
    };
    return x;
};
console.log(smallest());
```

Comment: You should probably confine yourself to the iterative solution with a loop or the recursive solution.

Comment: I hope to look back at this in one month and laugh at how bad my code was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **232792560** - It takes way too many recursions to get to this result. A stack overflow is inevitable in this case. If an iterative solution is good enough, you can use:

```
var smallest = function(_max) {
    var result = _max;
    for(var i = 1; i <= _max; i++) {
        if(result % i !== 0) {
            result++;
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
};

smallest(10); // => 2520
smallest(20); // => 232792560
```

Comment: Note: Don't even attempt `smallest(30)`, unless you're on some kind of super computer! :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I actually got a lot out of reading your answer.

I would give you an upvote, but don't have enough reputation yet!

Comment: Not a problem. Glad it helped. :)

Comment: this solution could be expressed as LCD (lowest common multiplier) of numbers from 1 to 20. Since LCD(a,b)* GCD(a,b)=a*b you just need eulers formula for GCD and that makes almost O(N) solution.